# How can I add some padding to the macvim text area

Tags: vim, macvim

I would like to add some padding between my text and the left edge of the window (or the right edge of the line numbers).

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I set the line number background to match the text background (black in both cases), so this gives a visual buffer between the numbers & the text.  I also set the line numbering to be dark grey so they are pretty unobtrusive.

Setting the line number background to match the text is simply a matter of removing the "bg" definitions from your `LineNr` definition entirely.  The relevant section of my colorscheme, including the current line highlighting, is this:

```
hi CursorLine   guibg=#333333
hi LineNr       guifg=#555555
```

So the end result looks like this:

[image]

(note I use relative line numbers via `set relativenumber`).

Answer (score 3):

`:help foldcolumn`

the foldcolumn is used normally to display fold-markers .. but that gives you space as well.

Comment: Unfortunately 'foldcolumn' doesn't appear between the number column and the buffer text.

Comment: @Heptite: good point.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the following commands in the Terminal to add some spacing around the MacVim window (the left spacing is inserted to the left of the line numbers, though):

```
defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTextInsetTop '10'
defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTextInsetLeft '10'
defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTextInsetBottom '10'
defaults write org.vim.MacVim MMTextInsetRight '10'
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/meleyal/1902879

Comment: This is really cool